# GNOME-Shell Password RePrompt Twice in a Row, Regardless

Tags: gnome, password

I have been getting these continually in Gnome Shell for the past year or so, different installs, on different machines and it's annoying. Lately it seems to occur every 12 hours or so. 
Here's the sequence: A password prompt appears for user, using my gmail address. The 1st dialogue box input is never accepted, regardless of what is entered. The subsequent 2nd one accepts anything it seems, and disappears silently. The cycle is repeated every n hours.I assume this is from the Online Accounts app? I use my email address for several accounts, so have no idea which account this is coming from.

Presently using Gnome-Shell 3.14 on Ubuntu Vivid Vervet, but as I've said have seen this on Debian installs, and on other machines running Gnome-Shell various versions.

Any suggestions? I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this in order to do a bug report.

Comment: As Byte Commander already said,  there's a good chance that it's a malware.  Get on a different pc on trusted network,  and change your password for that Gmail account.  On your machine , when popup shows up run xprop command,  click on that popup and tell us what is the output in terminal.  And if we don't find anything,  then back up your data and nuke that mowfunker from the orbit - wipe the drive and reinstall

Comment: And obviously , after you change password , do NOT enter it on your machine again

Comment: Hm OK. Not going to say it isn't malware, so will do so. Are there Linux exploits of this kind known?

Comment: I'm no security expert, but I'd say yeah. Linux malware/exploits exit even though they're not exactly as common as ones for Windows.  Then there's also possibility of an infected router. There's been a question on the forums where a guy had popups of advertisement in any browser he used, which later spread to another pc in his house. That's a good reason to set up admin password  on the router, not just wi-fi password

Comment: Yeah I'm worried more about my router, than the desktops in my home. I'm not convinced that this is an exploit run against me - just a fact that Gnome-Shell is in heavy development. I run a pretty tight ship and am not a newbie at this technology. However, my router is supplied by my ISP and doesn't seem to get firmware updates anymore. I'd love to use a WRT open source software on a router, but am not sure this ISP supplied one would support it. Thoughts?

Comment: Voting it to close since OP confirmed the nature of the dialog is same as of the linked question

Answer (score 0):

***NEVER*** use the same **username/email - password** combination for more than one service!

I advise you to *change all of them immediately*. Not only because it is unsafe in general, but because weird popup password requests look somehow suspicious to me.
It could be malware prompting you for your credentials to hack your accounts. It does not have to be, but it can be. Find out where it comes from and why!

And in general:
If you don't have a good reason for entering a password anywhere (because you yourself manually requested a service that needs it), **don't enter it**!

Comment: Actually I don't,(multiple factor auth is used for most accounts) and I'm rather positive this isn't malware as this has been happening for some time and usually starts after a (system update, from official sources). Additionally, this happens on a friends machine regularly too, after clean installs.

Comment: Well I think it's a thing with Gnome-Shell sometimes being too vague/simplistic. The dialogue is generic. I'm rather surprised other Gnome users haven't seen this behaviour.

Comment: I think this is the same bug http://goo.gl/XTAkQG this too, http://goo.gl/Kds4va

Comment: And another one which shows the dialogue asking for prompt: http://goo.gl/13LIMH So it seems to be a regression in both Debian and Ubuntu. :(

Answer (score 0):

Not positive, but seems to be the same as:
I bug goo.gl/XTAkQG this too, goo.gl/Kds4va –  Stephen Allen Apr 3 at 11:45

And another one which shows the dialogue asking for prompt: goo.gl/13LIMH So it seems to be a regression in both Debian and Ubuntu. :( –  Stephen Allen Apr 3 at 11:56